# What does this diagnostic output mean?

Tags: dsl-modem

I recently had a fault with my broadband connection. It turned out to be a fault with the ISP's or teleco's equipment. My ISP posted this diagnostic, but while I understand it in general, I'd like to to know more about the details.

I'm assuming that **ATM** means [Asynchronous Transfer Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Transfer_Mode) and **PPP** means [Point to Point Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol). It was this that my router was indicating as the fault.

> **xDSL Status Test Summary**
>   **Sync Status:**    Circuit In Sync
>
> **General Information**
>   **NTE Status:**     **NTE Power Status:**   Unknown **Bypass Status:**
>
> **Upstream DSL Link Information**   **Downstream DSL Link Information**
>   **Loop Loss:**  9.0 17.0
>   **SNR Margin:** 25  15
>   **Errored Seconds:**    0   0
>   **HEC Errors:** 0
>   **Cell Count:** 0   0
>   **Speed:**  448 8128
>   **TAM Status:** Successfully executed operation
>
> **Network Test: Sub-Test Results**
>   **Layer Name    Value   Status**
>   **Modem     pass**
>       Transmitter Power (Upstream)    12.4 dBm
>       Transmitter Power (Downstream)  8.8 dBm
>       Upstream psd    -38 dBm/Hz
>       Downstream psd  -51 dBm/Hz
>   **DSL       pass**
>       Equipment Vendor Name   TSTC
>       Equipment Vendor Id n/a
>       Equipment Vendor Revision   n/a
>       Training Time   8 s
>       Num Syncs   1
>       Upstream bit rate   448 kbps
>       Downstream bit rate 8128 kbps
>       Upstream maximum bit rate   1108 kbps
>       Downstream maximum bit rate 11744 kbps
>       Upstream Attenuation    3.5 dB
>       Downstream Attenuation  0.0 dB
>       Upstream Noise Margin   20.0 dB
>       Downstream Noise Margin 19.0 dB
>       Local CRC Errors    0
>       Remote CRC Errors   0
>       Up Data Path    interleaved
>       Down Data Path  interleaved
>       Standard Used   G_DMT
>   **INP**
>       INP Upstream Symbols    n/a
>       INP Upstream Delay  4 ms
>       INP Upstream Depth  4
>       INP Downstream Symbols  n/a
>       INP Downstream Delay    5 ms
>       INP Downstream Depth    32
>   **ATM   Reason:** No ATM cells received **fail**
>       Number of cells transmitted 30
>       Number of cells received    0
>       number of Near end HEC errors   0
>       number of Far end HEC errors    n/a
>   **PPP   Reason:** No response from peer **fail**
>       PAP authentication  nottested
>       CHAP authentication nottested

**UPDATE**

I've just had a status update from my ISP:

> The issue was with equipment and software at your local exchange which your services goes through

So no real help there in telling me whether it was a hardware or software problem.

Comment: Any particular bit?

Comment: @neurolysis - the bits that have **fail** next to them

Comment: Chris - I see your edit. That's your answer. The local exchange is the building that holds the other end of your phone line. What further answer are you looking for? They had a problem, they fixed it. What are you trying to find out, and why is this answer insufficient for you? Unless you were a telecom technician, more details won't help you out, and if you were a telecom technician, you'd be asking different questions.

Comment: @mfinni - I was curious as to whether it was a hardware or software issue. Saying "it was at the exchange" doesn't really answer that question.

Comment: They claim that it's both. Why does it matter to you? If you need more details, you can keep asking them and they may or may not give you answers that matter to you. None of us work there, so we can't give you the details you're after.

Comment: @mfinni - I was hoping that the diagnostics would indicate which it was, but if that's not the case then that's the answer.

Comment: OK - you're asking for way more details than an ISP would typically give an end-user. They showed you a trace from DSL equipment that found a problem at the ATM layer. The fixed the error and you're back up. Unless you're a telecom tech, telling you what was wrong won't mean much to you, and even if you were a tech but didn't work there, it still might not mean that much. Someone may have accidentally disabled your port. A line card may have fried. Who knows? Why does it matter?

Comment: @mfinni - curiosity, pure and simple ;)

Comment: Understood - if you want more true understanding of this stuff, you're just about going to have to go to work for an ISP or other telecom provider, or work for a company that has a lot of telecom needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to put dsl broadband to the most basic level, the telephone cable comes out at the exchange and goes in to splitter equipment, half goes to the telco/phone side, other goes to the ISP.

ATM is basically a physical transfer layer, it is level 1 on the OSI model, and used as the physical link.

PtPP gets performed at the link layer, it needs a physical connection (in your case, ATM) and is basically responsible for linking your device (in this case, a router) to the endpoint within your ISP.

So, from that log, ATM tried to transmit 30 frames/cells, but none were received back - a dead connection, or no one on the other end. Because of this, no PtPP can be established.

Comment: Given that there was nothing wrong with my hardware, where would have the fault been?

Comment: It is hard to know for certain without knowing your ISP's network, however, I would say that the problem was most likely at the local exchange as ATM is usually the earlies part of the connection. If it was within your ISP, it would most likely be ATM works but PtPP fail. The most common reason, believe it or not is network technicians unplugging incorrect cables.

Comment: +1, A DSL modem communicates with DSLAM equipment, which is what the test was run on (apparently). The ATM section shows cells trasmitted, and no near end failures, so the first hop in the ATM network worked, but something later didn't. It's impossible to tell exactly where, but one can assume it was a downed link in the ISDN/SoNet/Etc network. Most of these backhauls are redundant, so it's strange that it failed, but it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have told us that the ISP said the fault was on their equipment, what is it that you want us to tell you? They didn't have a fault on the line, because you have modem and DSL as a "PASS", so it was somewhere in their ATM equipment, most likely.

Comment: It's largely curiosity and wanting to know why something suddenly failed.

Comment: So ask them... Unless we worked there, we can't tell you any more than you've already been told.